# How to scroll to an element on a page when click a link in a separate Angular 7 mat-toolbar component

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material

I have an Angular 7 project with a mat-tool bar at the top of the page containing links. Below it is a long view made up of various sections. Each section is its own component. I achieved this by creating one component - Home - and then placed the component selectors for each section one under the other in home template. As such:

```
// Home component template
<app-intro></app-intro>
<app-ourservices></app-ourservices>
<app-ourwork></app-ourwork>
<app-contact></app-contact>
```

I want to be able to click a link in the mat-toolbar (which is its own component) and have the home page scroll to a relevant section WITH animation.

The following works, but it causes the view to jump to the section.

```
<a href="home#servicesSection">Services</a>
```

I am also aware of using a click event combined with .scrollIntoView:

```
scroll(element: HTMLElement) {
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
  }
```

But this only seems to work when everything (id tags, and click events) are contained within the same component (i.e on the same page).

How can I achieve what I am trying to do but still keep things separated into components? I am new to Angular so might be structuring things incorrectly.

Comment: You could wrap each of your custom components in a div with an id or class, and then use scrollIntoView on the wrappers. I assume you tried directly on the component html tag already ?

Comment: @Shannon yes, you were right. Instead of passing the element (which the component knew nothing of) I passed in the id and then used document.getElementWithId to get a ref to the element I needed to scroll to. Post the answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML - Give the elements reference variables `#nameHere`

```
<div #intro>
    <app-intro></app-intro>
</div>
<div #ourservices>
    <app-ourservices></app-ourservices>
<div #ourwork>
    <app-ourwork></app-ourwork>
</div>
<div #contact>
    <app-contact></app-contact>
</div>
```

In your .ts file - Use `@ViewChild` to get  reference to the element using the reference variables, then use the `navtiveElement` with `scrollIntoView()`

```
import { ... ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

....

@ViewChild('intro') intro: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('ourserivces') ourservices: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('ourwork') ourwork: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('contact') contact: ElementRef;

contstructor(....)


public scrollToIntro() {
    this.intro.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
        inline: 'nearest'
    });
}

public scrollToOurServices() {
    this.ourserivces.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
        inline: 'nearest'
    })
}

public scrollToOurWork() {
    this.ourwork.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
        inline: 'nearest'
    })
}

public scrollToContact() {
    this.contect.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
        inline: 'nearest'
    })
}
```

Usage - in your HTML

```
<div (click)="scrollToIntro()">Intro</div>
<div (click)="scrollToOurServices()">Services</div>
<div (click)="scrollToOurWork()">Our Work</div>
<div (click)="scrollToContact()">Contact</div>
```